# Python 3 replacement for PyFile_AsFile

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, ffi

The following code works in Python 2:

```
from ctypes import *

## Setup python file -> c 'FILE *' conversion :
class FILE(Structure):
    pass
FILE_P = POINTER(FILE)
PyFile_AsFile = pythonapi.PyFile_AsFile # problem here
PyFile_AsFile.argtypes = [py_object]
PyFile_AsFile.restype = FILE_P
fp = open(filename,'wb')
gd.gdImagePng(img, PyFile_AsFile(fp))
```

But in Python 3, there is no PyFile_AsFile in pythonapi.

The code is an except from [testPixelOps.py](http://www.langarson.com.au/code/testPixelOps/testPixelOps.py).

Comment: Looks like there's a solution [here](http://www.salstar.sk/pub/svplayer/vlc.py), but it segfaults for me.

Comment: Ah, I know why it segfaulted. I was using the file descriptor as a FILE*...

Comment: It is perfectly fine answer your own question and accept it, if of course there are no other better answers

Comment: @jamylak: I didn't find the answer. I just found out I did something wrong. I don't think it's actually a solution any more, cause they just import different API functions depending on the version, but they don't actually use them.

Comment: Why do you want to call `PyFile_AsFile` using ctypes? You use ctypes to reach things that are not available using Python.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I just needed a way to convert a file object to a ctypes FILE* so that I can pass it to GD. I.e. I am just looking for a Python 3 equivalent of the above. PyFile_AsFile is indeed available using Python 2, as this piece of code demonstrates.

Comment: I certainly never said that `PyFile_AsFile` was not available. Just that it was an odd thing to be using in the first place.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9629271/1046299

Comment: Python 3 still has something similar to `PyFile_AsFile`, but it is a two-step process now.  What used to be `FILE *fp = PyFile_AsFile(p)` is now [`FILE *fp = fdopen(PyObject_AsFileDescriptor(p), "r")`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/file.html#c.PyObject_AsFileDescriptor).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I just needed a way to convert a file object to a ctypes FILE* so that I can pass it to GD.

You are out of luck. That was possible in Python 2.x, but is not possible in Python 3.x. The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/c-api/file.html) explains why not:

> These APIs are a minimal emulation of the Python 2 C API for built-in file objects, which used to rely on the buffered I/O (FILE*) support from the C standard library. In Python 3, files and streams use the new io module, which defines several layers over the low-level unbuffered I/O of the operating system.

If you want a `FILE*` you are going to have to make one yourself, using the C standard library directly.

Comment: Thank you David, I was stupid for not reading the header of that doc page.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find a real answer to the problem, but I found out that if you don't need to convert the Python file object to a `FILE*` (i.e., you don't need to "share" the opened file), you can just use `ctypes` to call `fopen` from `libc` and get the `FILE*` like that.

Comment: And [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17257911) shows how to call `fopen` from `libc`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[py3c_PyFile_AsFileWithMode](https://py3c.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fileshim.html) can be referred.The PyFile API Documentation states it as

> a quick-and-dirty replacement for PyFile_AsFile()