# Using python ctypes and libc to write void pointer to binary file

Tags: python, ctypes, fwrite, void-pointers, libc

I am using python ctypes and libc to interface with a vendor-provided DLL file.  The purpose of the DLL file is to acquire an image from a camera.

The image acquisition appears to run without error; the issue I am having is accessing the data.

The image acquisition function takes a ctypes.c_void_p as an argument for the image data.

simplified as follows:

```
"""
typedef struct AvailableData
{
    void* initial_readout;
    int64 readout_count;
} imageData;
"""

class AvailableData(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("initial_readout", ctypes.c_void_p), 
                ("readout_count", ctypes.c_longlong)]

"""
Prototype
Acquire(
CamHandle                 camera,
int64                       readout_count,
int                       readout_time_out,
AvailableData*         available,
AcquisitionErrorsMask* errors );
"""

>>> imageData = AvailableData()
>>> Acquire.argtypes = CamHandle, ctypes.c_longlong, ctypes.c_int, 
         ctypes.POINTER(AvailableData), ctypes.POINTER(AcquisitionErrorsMask)
>>> Acquire.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

>>> status = Acquire(camera, readout_count, readout_time_out, imageData, errors)
```

I do not fully understand exactly what the function is doing, because after I run the function, `imageData.initial_readout` appears to be a type 'long' (not even a ctypes.c_long: just 'long').  However, it also has a value associated with it.  I'm assuming this is a starting address of where the data is stored.

```
>>> type(imageData.initial_readout)
<type 'long'>
>>> imageData.initial_readout
81002560L
```

My current approach for accessing the data is to use libc.fopen, libc.fwrite, libc.fclose as follows:

```
>>> libc = ctypes.cdll.msvcrt

>>> fopen = libc.fopen
>>> fwrite = libc.fwrite
>>> fclose = libc.fclose
>>> fopen.argtypes = ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p
>>> fopen.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

>>> fopen.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
>>> fwrite.argtypes = ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.c_void_p
>>> fwrite.restype = ctypes.c_size_t

>>> fclose = libc.fclose
>>> fclose.argtypes = ctypes.c_void_p,
>>> fclose.restype = ctypes.c_int

>>> fp = fopen('output3.raw', 'wb')
>>> print 'fwrite returns: ',fwrite(ctypes.c_void_p(imageData.initial_readout), readoutstride.value, 1, fp)
fwrite returns:  0
>>> fclose(fp)
```

where `readoutstride = 2097152` corresponding to a 1024x1024 array of 16 bit pixels.

**The file "output3.raw" shows up in windows explorer, however, it has 0 kbytes and when I try to open it with (e.g. with an imag viewer) it says the file is empty.**

I see that `fwrite` returns a value of 0 (but should return a value of 1)

If you have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong here, I appreciate it immensely.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: @eryksun I've included a prototype for acquire in my edits this morning.  Also, strictly speaking imageData is a structure, which then contains a void pointer (I left out these details to simplify the initial question).  However, since you've asked I've modified my code above to include the full structure.  Hopefully this clarifies things.

Comment: @eryksun `readout_count` is the number of frames being collected.  When I call the `Acquire` function, its 2nd argument is `readout_count`, which I specify to be 1.  After running `Acquire` this value gets assigned to `imageData.readout_count`. `readoutstride` specifies the  number of bytes in a stride (frame).   There is  an additional function that I can call (before Acquiring) that returns the `readoutsride`.  The value it returns is `2097152`, which corresponds to 2 bytes per pixel at 1024x1024 pixels.

Comment: @eryksun it seems to me that there is indeed a byte string stored in memory (at the address given by available.initial_readout).  Is there a way in Python to access the next`2097152` bytes beginning at a given memory address, e.g. `81002560L` or in hex `0x4d40040L`?

Comment: If the call was successful, there are lots of way to create the string. One way is to use `ctypes.string_at(address, size)` Afterward, call the library's function that frees the memory.

Answer (score 6):

Specify `argtypes`, `restype` of the functions.

```
import ctypes

libc = ctypes.windll.msvcrt

fopen = libc.fopen
fopen.argtypes = ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p,
fopen.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

fwrite = libc.fwrite
fwrite.argtypes = ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.c_size_t, ctypes.c_void_p
fwrite.restype = ctypes.c_size_t

fclose = libc.fclose
fclose.argtypes = ctypes.c_void_p,
fclose.restype = ctypes.c_int

fp = fopen('output3.raw', 'wb')
fwrite('Hello', 5, 1, fp)
fclose(fp)
```

Comment: I modified my code to include specification of `argstypes` and `restype`.  I still have the same issue-- feel free to check out my updates to the question above.  Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: @J.Lowney, You have to specify argtypes, restype not only for fopen, fwrite, fclose, but also acquire, ....

Comment: @J.Lowney, Change `ctypes.c_void_p(available.initial_readout)` to `ctypes.addressof(available.initial_readout)`.

Comment: When I modify to `ctypes.addressof(imageData.initial_readout)` I get an error:`TypeError: invalid type`.  The confusing part is, before I passed the structure to the function, `available.initial_readout` was defined as `ctypes.c_void_p`.  When I get it back from the function it is a type `long` -- so I think python is converting it back to a python variable.  As a result of this I think I've lost the `ctypes.addressof` information.

Comment: Are `argstype`, `argtypes` and `argstypes` somehow aliases? I seem to find all on the internet (mostly `argtypes` though).

Comment: @Shahbaz, According to [`ctypes` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._FuncPtr.argtypes), only `argtypes` is the right one.