# How to avoid memory leak with shared_ptr and SWIG

Tags: c++, python, file-io, memory-leaks, swig

I'm trying to use `boost::shared_ptr`'s to allow for me to use c++ file I/O stream objects in my python script.  However, the generated wrapper warns me that it is leaking memory.

Here's a minimal `.i` file exhibiting the problem:

```
%module ptrtest

%include "boost_shared_ptr.i"
%include "std_string.i"

%shared_ptr( std::ofstream )

%{
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

typedef boost::shared_ptr< std::ofstream > ofstream_ptr;

ofstream_ptr mk_out(const std::string& fname ){
    return ofstream_ptr( new std::ofstream( fname.c_str() ) );
}

%}

ofstream_ptr mk_out(const std::string& fname );


%pythoncode %{

def leak_memory():
    ''' demonstration function -- when I call
        this, I get a warning about memory leaks
    ''''
    ostr=mk_out('/tmp/dont_do_this.txt')


%}
```

Here's the warning:

```
In [2]: ptrtest.leak_memory()
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'ofstream_ptr *', no destructor found.
```

Is there a way to modify the `.i` file to tell the interface how to dispose of the shared_ptr properly?

Comment: Refreshing to see a question with a complete, minimal example that makes it easy to answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your example is missing two parts to get the destructor to run:

1. Since SWIG knows absolutely nothing about `std::ofstream` the default behaviour is to do nothing beyond pass an opaque handle around. See [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13593596/168175) for a further discussion of this.

   The fix here is to supply an empty definition for `std::ofstream` in your interface file to convince SWIG it knows enough to do more, even if you don't plan on exposing any members.
2. SWIG needs to see the typedef itself - inside the `%{ %}` it just gets passed straight to the output module, not used in the wraping itself.

Thus your example becomes:

```
%module ptrtest

%include "boost_shared_ptr.i"
%include "std_string.i"

%shared_ptr( std::ofstream )

namespace std {
  class ofstream {
  };
}

%{
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

typedef boost::shared_ptr< std::ofstream > ofstream_ptr;

ofstream_ptr mk_out(const std::string& fname ){
    return ofstream_ptr( new std::ofstream( fname.c_str() ) );
}
%}

typedef boost::shared_ptr< std::ofstream > ofstream_ptr;
ofstream_ptr mk_out(const std::string& fname );

%pythoncode %{
def leak_memory():
    ostr=mk_out('/tmp/dont_do_this.txt')
%}
```

For future reference you can avoid duplication of stuff that lives only in the .i file with `%inline`:

```
%inline %{
typedef boost::shared_ptr< std::ofstream > ofstream_ptr;

ofstream_ptr mk_out(const std::string& fname ){
    return ofstream_ptr( new std::ofstream( fname.c_str() ) );
}
%}
```

Which declares, defines and wraps it all in one shot.