# How to send python list to C++ application awaiting input?

Tags: python, c++, data-transfer

I am writing a python script that generates a list of integers and is supposed to send this list to a concurrently running C++ program that is constantly awaiting input. What is a quick and painless way to design the link between these two languages?

I have considered possibilities such as:

- writing the python result to a file, while listening for file updates in C++ and loading it as soon as new data is available.
- using python pexpect package and including a command line interface in the C++ program, so that it receives the data through cin.

Both above possibilities seem a bit too hacky to me. Are there better options, which would not require to become an expert in C++ library coding for python?

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18860898/5369706. Thinking you can write to standard output and input in Python and catch the stream in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a Socket and an OutputStream in the python app to send the data, and another Socket and an InputStream in the C++ program to receive the data.

Comment: I was under the impression that sockets bind to IPs and ports and are designed for internet communication. Is there a way to set up sockets purely locally? Or are you suggesting to send the data through the internet?

Comment: Yes there is, on your python app, when creating a new socket you can just use a "not reserved" port like "7778" and use localhost(which is usually 127.0.0.1) to connect to the same machine, for example, create a new socket with 'new Socket("localhost", 7778)'. And in your c++ you just need to set up a new Socket on the same port (7778, for example).

Comment: This is great, I'll certainly give this a try! Accepting this answer, at least until something even better comes around.